# Creating abstract classes or interfaces for querying MySQL tables using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm implementing an application that does basic queries on a mysql database, 
e.g. update, insert, delete. 
And I was wondering if anyone out there is as paranoid as me when it comes
to concatenating strings for queries, so instead they've written abstract methods
to do this so that it works on all tables and avoids easy typos.

This is my way of avoiding terrible errors in concatenation, but I would like to 
see what others have done as well to broaden my ways.

Here's my method in pseudocode;

Say I have a mysql table named ACC that contains the following columns:

```
acc_no (primary key) | acc_first_name |  acc_last_name 
123                  |John            | Smith
```

Then I implemented a java abstract class

```
public abstract class Acc{
  // All column values in the table Acc as constants
  public static final String NUM = "acc_no";
  public static final String FIRST_NAME = "acc_first_name";
  public static final String LAST_NAME = "acc_last_name";

  private Hashtable<String, String> hash = new Hashtable<String, String>();

  public Acc(Connection con, String acc_no){
    // Get values from mysql
    PreparedStatement pstmt = ...SELECT * FROM ACC where ACC_NO = acc_no ....
    ResultSet rs = resultset from pstmt

    //Then put all the resultset rs values in hash so the hashtable have key/values             
    //that look something like this:
    //[[NUM, "123"]
    // [FIRST_NAME, "John"]
    // [LAST_NAME, "Smith"]]
    // The key is one of the constants in this class
    // and the corresponding values are taken from mysql database
  }


  public String get(String column){
    return hash.get(column)
  }
}
```

So when you want to access a value in the table from a class that extends it,
it would be something like

```
class AccApp extends Acc{

   AccApp(Connection con){
     super(con, "123")
     printName(); 
   }

   String printName(){
      // Notice that I use static constants to get the column values
      // instead of typing this.get("acc_first_name") and this.get("acc_last_name")
      System.out.println(this.get(Acc.FIRST_NAME) + this.get(Acc.LAST_NAME));
   }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered an ORM like Hibernate?  It does things like this for you.

Comment: Don't do it just use DTO/DAO pattern.

Comment: I am not sure what problems you have with concatentation, but if it is about concatenating values in query condition, then use a parametrized query using `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Thanks ryan1234! I wish I had known this sooner!

Comment: Mark Rotteveel, what do you mean by using a "parameterized query" using preparedstatement, could you give an example? thanks. 
(I would prefer to concatenation just because it is
1. easy to make grammar errors e.g. forgetting to put quote marks, forgetting a space, making a spelling error
2. it's not object oriented so it hinders the ability to make full use of java's capabilities